# Properties in nested classes in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I keep running into the error "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class".  I'm working on a VB.NET MVC application.  I have a model that has top level security Properties contained within the top level class that should be available to classes within that class.  My properties always follow this structure:

```
    Private _SecurityVar = Nothing
    Public Shared Property SecurityVar
        Get
            If _SecurityVar = Nothing Then
                _SecurityVar = User.IsInRole("SecurityFunction")
            End If
            Return _SecurityVar
        End Get
        Set(value)

        End Set
    End Property
```

My problem is is that I can't access _SecurityVar b/c it's not shared.  I don't want _SecurityVar available within my view, just SecurityVar.  I then need to access these top level variables from within classes that are contained within this class, such as a list of orders. I don't want to simply return User.IsInRole("SecurityFunction") because I would then be hitting the database multiple times; which would be extremely inefficient, especially when it comes to building a large table.  How do I get around this, is there a better way?

Comment: I find the best way to do this is to make the sub-classes "Aware" of their parent. Sharing is a very loose and, in my mind, bad programming practice.

Comment: Something in your design doesn't fell natural to me, but I can't think of a reasonable way to tell you 'why' withouth knowing more about it or telling you to redesing the whole thing. With that out of the way: you just have to make you `Private _SecutiryVar` shared too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sharing.. make your subclasses aware of their parentage.

In the subclass add

```
Private myParent as <ParentClassName>
Public Sub New(Parent as <ParentClassName>)
   MyParent = Parent
End Sum
```

In the parent class create the subclass using

```
Dim Child as New <YourSubClassName>(Me)
```

Then when you need something from the parent in the subclass

```
Var = myParent.<Property Name>
```

If you plan on moving those subclasses around you also need to make the _Parent Public or add a method so you can change it later.

If you don't want to allow the subclass full access to the parent class you can "group" your shared variables in another class in the parent and pass that instead.

Comment: This worked after I switched a few things around.  Why was it voted down?  What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: I was the victim of a troll.. quite a few of my posts got voted down in a minute or so.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your private variable shared too

```
Private Shared _SecurityVar = Nothing
```

Comment: This is what I had been doing but I didn't want _SecurityVar to be available in my views.

Comment: It is `Private`, it **shouldn't** be available anywhere else than this class, even if its shared.